# How can you determine if the object initializer is the one calling the Add method?

Tags: c#, object-initializers, collection-initializer

I have a custom `Vector` class that can be initialized several ways.  It has the following constructor to create a vector of a given length with all zeros.

```
public Vector(int length) { ... }
```

or it can use an object initializer by implementing `IEnumerable` and an `Add(..)` method like this to fill out a given vector

```
var v1 = new Vector{ 1, 2, 5 };
```

The problem lies in the fact that you can write the following code

```
var v1 = new Vector(3){ 1, 2, 5 };
```

this looks innocent enough, but it ends up creating a vector of length 6 where the first three values are 0 and then the next 3 are 1,2,5.  Ideally this would return just a vector of length 3 with values of 1,2,5.  I have gone through and stepped through the object intialization of this and there does not seem to be any indication that the object is being created.  It appears as though the constructor runs, and then 3 `Add()` methods are being called.  How can I tell that it is an object initializer calling the `Add()` method and protect the method from creating additional values?

p.s. As is evident in the comment section the API for this class isn't great as it stands in the question.  Still a work in progress, but I appreciate the commentary as it helped me flush out my ideas a little further.  I'm leaving the question as is so the comments make sense.

Comment: Why does a `length` argument add elements to the underlying array? That can be very confusing to the caller.

Comment: I would suggest your `Vector(3)` to me would indicate a `capacity` not an element. So your implementation seems off.

Comment: You can't tell, the compiler converts the initialiser into a sequence of `Add` calls. The real problem is that your API is confusing.

Comment: You can add a break point and then look at the "trace stack" which you can add from the view menu.

Comment: Vector(3) creates a class that has a capacity for 3 doubles.

Comment: Why are you creating a custom collection in the first place?  Just use `List<T>`

Comment: @Servy I am creating a custom class so I can implement Vector math.  Doing List<T> + List<T> doesn't make a bunch of sense.

Comment: @PlTaylor That's not what you wrote in the question. In the question, you say `Vector(3)` sets the length to 3. The length and the capacity are two different things. I too would expect `Vector(3)` to only set the capacity to 3. Which would mean the length would be zero, but the `Add` methods won't require allocations.

Comment: @PlTaylor, OK, so you need a `capacity` and a `length`. Your `Vector(int length)` should really be `Vector(int capacity)` and only change the `length` when you add items.

Comment: @hvd I have always seen capacity and length as interchangable terms.  Can you point to definitions where they are different so I can better see your point?

Comment: @PlTaylor Then just have your `Vector` be a wrapper around a `List<T>` and emulate its semantics for the operations you expose.

Comment: @PlTaylor .NET's own `List<T>` uses them differently, uses them the same way the commenters here use them.

Comment: @PlTaylor, see c#'s `ArrayList` class for an example. It has both `Capacity` and `Length` with separate meanings.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz `ArrayList` has been obsolete for 10 years.  You should be looking at `List<T>`.

Comment: @Servy ::rollseyes:: It answered the question, therefore it's relevant.

Comment: The goal was to have a Vector that had an Immutable length, the only reason I implemented an Add() was to be able to initialize vectors with values easily.  Trying to feel out a reasonable API for this as it doesn't have one yet.

Comment: @PlTaylor If you want it to be immutable, then you shouldn't add public methods to mutate it.

Comment: @Servy just trying to find a balancing point of ease of use and ideal implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a *design problem*. Instead of going around and trying to tell that the compiler is going to invoke your `Add` method, I would change the `Vector` constructor to have an overload receiving the actual values, or an array of them:

```
public Vector(double x, double y, double z)
```

Or

```
public Vector(params double[] values)
```

Where the default constructor would hold the default values for the elements without actually adding anything to the underlying array.

Comment: The vector will not always be of length 3, but your second point is really valid.

Comment: That point is well received.  Playing around with implementations now.

Comment: For the record the best balance I have found so far is to implement the param constructor and get rid of the object intialization all together.  But it is still a work in progress.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell that it is an object intializer calling the Add() method and protect the method from creating additional values?

You don't.  The code is functionally identical to:

```
var v1 = new Vector(3);
v1.Add(1);
v1.Add(2);
v1.Add(3);
```

As far as your class is concerned, the two usages are indistinguishable.

You can ensure that anyone who writes *that* has it function however you think it should, and the collection initializer code will do the same thing.